# Why can't I define top-level extension methods in C# 9?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I had thought that using the [Top-Level Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/exploration/top-level-statements) feature in C# 9 essentially wraps your top-level code in the usual `Program` class and `Main` method.

A decompiled top-level program looks like this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
internal static class $Program
{
    private static void $Main(string[] args)
    {
        // top-level code here
    }
}
```

You can define normal methods at the top-level. They are compiled into the `Program` class, but outside of the `Main` method, where extension methods can also be defined.

Because the generated `Program` class is static and non-generic, I would expect to be able to define extension methods at the top level. However, I get compiler error `CS1106: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class`

[image: VS Code compiler error CS1106: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class]

Why is this?

Comment: Why can't you create your extensions in a static class in another file? You should be able to use them in the top level statements.

Comment: @TimSchmelter He can. He doesn't want to. Because he's exploring C# language concepts.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that's what I've opted for, I'm just interested in why really :)

Comment: @IanKemp: Ok, but he is allowed to mix top level statements and use existing code at the same time. Otherwise the top level statements would be pretty useless. You need to convert that "proof of concept" code into production code, so you extract classes and methods which still have to work before you are finished. And of course thoses classes belong into their own files.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Again, this is not a real-life scenario. It's asking "according to my understanding of the spec I should be able to do X, but when I try to do it the compiler complains, is there a problem with my understanding"?

Comment: This feature looks like a significant simplification of language syntax (structure) for very simple programms, written by beginners, perhaps for scripts also? As a seasoned programmer you shouldn't really be using it for real projects. It's also inconsistent as one file structure will differ from others in solution.

Comment: @Sinatr Please read my previous comment to TimSchmelter. This is not about how useful a feature is (perceived to be) or is not, it's about whether that feature should work according to the language spec.

Comment: @Sinatr: i also dont see the big advantage but on the contrary it discourages unexperienced developers from creating re-usable OOP code if they have already created something working in a top level statement.

Comment: [The language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#extension-methods) says "Extension methods can only be declared in non-generic, non-nested static classe". **Declared**. It doesn't matter whether top-level methods are _implemented_ using a static class, the fact is that the language spec requires that extension methods are declared in a static class, and top-level methods are not declared in any class.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I expect you can't do many things with it (i.e. not only extension methods aren't working, but more) and that it's all documented. Is it not documented? Why OP expects extension methods (which require static class and he is not using `class` at all) to work?

Comment: i find this inconsistent too partly because csx script requires extension method to be declared outside of a static class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [C# Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#extension-methods) says:

> When the first parameter of a method includes the `this` modifier, that method is said to be an ***extension method***. Extension methods can only be declared in non-generic, non-nested static classes.

According to the language specification, extension methods must be **declared** in a static class.

It does not matter that top-level methods are *implemented* by placing them in a hidden static class. Top-level methods are (by definition) not declared in *any* class, and therefore cannot be extension methods according to the specification.

As with all language design questions, this is the way that it is because this is the way that the language design team designed the language. Presumably the same concerns which prevent you from defining extension methods inside non-static classes also apply to top-level methods.

You can open a discussion in the [csharplang repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions) or ask a question [on Gitter](https://gitter.im/dotnet/csharplang) if you want someone with more authority to possibly give more detail.

Comment: *"Presumably the same concerns which prevent you from defining extension methods inside non-static classes"* - and a great thing too. Otherwise youg jedi devs would be splattering them everywhere. Anyway, great post

Comment: Discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4526

Comment: @IanKemp nice post for clarification, and in hindsight the specs make perfect sense for both reasoning and clarification. There is no reason why they couldn't do this, but it seems like a counter intuitive hack

Answer (score 4):

The top-level statement feature is implemented the way you described it: your top level code is wrapped into the compiler generated class **and `Main` method**.

Your extension cannot be declared inside this `Main` method, so your syntax is invalid. An extension declaration is not a top-level statement.

Comment: Interestingly though, writing normal methods at the top-level puts them inside the `Program` class but outside of the `Main` method. I'd expect extension methods to work here

Comment: @Connell oh ok, didn't know that...this really seems a bit inconsistent.

Comment: @Connell Might be useful/pertinent to add that info into the question, perhaps with an actual example of a top-level class with a normal method and the resultant decompiled code.

Answer (score 2):

According to Mads Torgersen in [this video from .NET Conf 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3kWzPKoRXc&t=165s) any functions declared as top-level statements are local functions within the `main()` method, rather than methods on the `Program` class.

Local functions cannot be extension methods.

Comment: That's not how Roslyn actually generates the code, though, as per @MindSwipe's answer. Mads might have been mistaken or things might have changed since then.

Comment: @IanKemp It is, though. Remember that local functions get lifted into methods on the containing class, so local functions inside a `Main` will get lifted into methods on the (compiler-generated) class containing `Main`. [This shenanigans with the `ref` display class](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQEsB2MIIA4D2ANrBACarIwJYDmqAxgZlVNsgDRkgDUAPgAEAjADphATgAUAIgASEIkQIACAOoEERMtICUAbgCwAKGPCADMoAeygLzLpYAgWmGTRgQBZlAEQIBlAgBbCAAVAAs6SR1jAG9jZQTlYTEhKUt9YwBfIA) is what you'd expect with a local function.

Comment: @canton7 This answer is saying that top-level functions get converted to **local functions within the generated Main method**. You and I are saying (and Roslyn via SharpLab confirms) that top-level functions get converted to **top-level methods within the generated Program class**.

Comment: Can it be both? So top-level functions are converted to local functions in the `Main` method, which are then, as a second step, lifted into the `Program` class, as part of the how the compiler treats all local functions?

Comment: @IanKemp Connell is saying exactly what I was trying to say. You'll never see a local function in disassembled IL, because local functions are lifted into methods on the containing class. You're seeing methods on the containing (compiler-generated) class, and saying "these are top-level functions and not local functions", but the top-level functions could absolutely have been converted into local functions within `Main`, and then into methods on the containing class. In fact, the way that they're treated (re that `ref` struct display class for example) is identical to local functions

Comment: For comparison: [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQEsB2MIIA4D2ANrBACarIwJYDmqAxgZlVNsgDRkgDUAPlhwJMUIgAIAAgEYAbJIBMkqQHYAsACgA3hrG6xeGgDdSSuRIAsYgLJQsACmkAGANoBdMVAS1kASh17tdT1gpQA6aQBOOwAiAAkIIiICMQB1AgQiMmifAG5/ELF8kKcxAA8xAF4xaLACAmi89SLgizEAEQIAZQIAWwgAFQALOjs/IIKxQIniqXCpKNLc5r0AXyK19Q2NIA===) is the equivilent of the code @canton7 posted earlier, using an explicit main method & local function. [This](https://www.diffchecker.com/YaUuPIRy) is a diff of the compiled outputs - they are nearly identical.

Answer (score 1):

Using [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/) we can see that, yes, the generated `Program` is static, and multiple methods declared in a top level context do get compiled correctly (example [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQEsB2MIIA4D2ANrBACarIwJYDmqAxgZlVNsgDRkgDUAPgAEAjADphATgAUAIgASEIkQIACAOoEERMtICUAbgCwAKGMCALMoAiBAMoEAthAAqACzqSdxgN7Hlf5cJiQlJyCkpqGlq6hkYAvkA)), something is missing when comparing to extension methods: The `[Extension]` attribute, as both the class and method need to be marked with this, official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute?view=net-5.0).

This is the code generated by a top level `Hello World` (some things omited for brevity, full thing [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQEsB2MIIA4D2ANrBACarIwJYDmqAxgZlVNsgDRkgDUAPgAEAjADphATgAUAIgASEIkQIACAOoEERMtICUAbgCwAKGPCAbMoEAmZQDECBYwG9jyt5aEWBAFjU0cACoEAMLMyMQQkjAAFujIHgAMyuGIDBA6ygC8AHweYkJSKQhp+sYAvkA===))

```cs
[assembly: Extension]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
[CompilerGenerated]
internal static class <Program>$
{
    private static void <Main>$(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Now here's the decompiled code for a class with an extension method:

```cs
[Extension]
internal static class Foo
{
    [Extension]
    private static void WriteToConsole(string source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(source);
    }
}
```

Seems like the compiler isn't recognizing that there are extension methods, and as such isn't compiling it correctly. We also can't forcibly place the `Extension` attribute, as we then get an error saying that

> error CS1112: Do not use 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute'. Use the 'this' keyword instead

And even if we could, we can't place it on the `Program` class itself

**TL;DR**: The C# compiler doesn't recognize that there are extension methods in the top level statements, and as such doesn't apply the necessary `[Extension]` attribute to the class or the method

Comment: So in other words, this appears to either be a compiler bug or a language feature oversight.

Comment: Probably an oversight. It may be worth posting an issue on the [Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) if we want to get a definitive answer

Comment: @MindSwipe Don't post this to Roslyn. This sort of questions lives in [csharplang discussions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions), since it's a language specification concern.

Comment: Asked: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4526

Answer (score 1):

To attempt and answer to my own question with a suspicion.

I wonder if this was a design choice, and that top-level methods are actually [Local Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) in the `Main` method, rather than methods in the `Program` class.

With a local function, methods are also compiled into the class but outside of the method they are defined in the source code. The generated method names also look very similar, like `<$Main>g__Test`.

Attempting to write the same extension method as a local function gives me the same compiler error:

[image: Local function error CS1106: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class]